# Ruby on Rails -- a link doesn't work in an email generated by ActionMailer

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, url

I've read the "[Action Mailer Basics Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html)". Here is my code:

```
def send_email
  @url = 'my url'
  mail(to: 'my email address', subject: 'my subject')
end
```

Here is my template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type'>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      Hi. This is your notification.
    </p>
    <p>
      Please click this link: <%= @url %>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

That is the same as in the guide. The problem is that `<%= @url %>` is not formatted as a link when the email is received. The link by itself is fine.

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thta's because you didn't wrap it with `<a>`, so it's displayed as plain text. Try this:

```
<%= link_to "Link", @url %>
```

It would generate HTML:

```
<a href="my url">Link</a>
```

Comment: Well that was easy. Works perfectly. Why doesn't the method defined in the action mailer work? I am using rails 4. Is that the problem?

Comment: @ Danil Speransky Yes I always do that but I have to wait for the 10 minute before I can accept. I can upvote but it's not displayed until I reach a certain score on stack overflow.